# Logging in flask with gunicorn

Tags: logging, flask, gunicorn

I am a developer transitioning from Java to Python.

I have a flask application which is deployed on gunicorn. For debugging the application I have used loggers as below

```
#For logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import logging
from logging import Formatter


logger = logging.getLogger('backend-logging')
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
#EOL
```

In each file the above code snippet is used to log the error,debug,info messages.

```
logger.info('creating user with the data %s',json.dumps(data))
```

Here is my wsgi application

```
from server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When i am starting my application using the below command it is not printing the loggers.

```
gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --log-level DEBUG wsgi:app
```

Could someone help me if this the right way to log application logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `--access-logfile` and `--error-logfile` as `'-'`, while running your Gunicorn. This tells `gunicorn` to send error and access log to `stdout` stream.

Example

> ```
> # make sure to give --access-logfile and --error-logfile as '-' to make gunicorn send logs to stdout
> gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 2 -k gevent --timeout 300 --worker-connections 1000 --max-requests 1000000 --limit-request-line 8190 --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-'
> ```

Maybe this can help. Its using python's `dictConfig` to set up logging.

[Setting up logging for Gunicorn in a Flask application using Python's dictConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257818/setting-up-logging-for-gunicorn-in-a-flask-application-using-pythons-dictconfig/61258002#61258002)